# Prove that if $a \equiv b\pmod m \land n\mid m \land n>0 \Rightarrow a \equiv b \pmod n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

$a \equiv b\pmod m \land n\mid m \land n>0 \Rightarrow a \equiv b \pmod n$

I tried:

$$n\mid m \Leftrightarrow m = kn \\
a \equiv b\pmod {kn} \\
a/kn = q_1 + b \\
a/m = q_2+b$$

What do I do next?

Comment: Do you mean $a/(kn)=q_1+b/(kn)$?

Comment: @ajotatxe No because it's saying that a is congruent with b in mod kn, which means that if you divide a by kn you get remainder b. I think.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use the definition of congruence? $x\equiv y\pmod{k}$ if and only if $k$ divides $x-y$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**:

You just have to prove that if $m\mid a-b$ and $n\mid m$, then $n\mid a-b$, which should be pretty easy.

Comment: The closest I got was $a-b = k_1m, a-b = k_2n$, and that $m = kn$. What do I do next?

Comment: In the first equality subsitute the third (both constitute the hypothesis) to obtain the second, which is the conclusion. What is $k_2$ is function of $k_1$ and $k$?.

Comment: $a-b = k_1 * kn$?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly that.

Comment: Right, $k_1*kn$ is a multiple of n so $a\equiv b(\mod m) = a \equiv  b(\mod k_1k*n)$... how do you prove this last equality?

Comment: You seem to confuse some notion: you've checked that $a-b$ is a multiple of $n$ (with quotient $k_2=k_1k$), and this suffices to say that $a-b\equiv 0\pmod n$, which is the same as $a\equiv b \pmod n$. Unrelated, but useful: you have a `\pmod{n}` command to denote the modular equivalence with parentheses (and proper spacing).

Comment: I think I got it, thanks!

Comment: It is by definition the quotient of $a-b$  by $n$, and you've just found that $a-b=(k_1k)n$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$
a\equiv b \ \bmod m \Rightarrow a= b+km, \ k\in\mathbb{Z}
$$

furthermore

$$
n\mid m\Rightarrow m=ln,\ \ l\in\mathbb{Z}.
$$

Combine these two and reduce modulo $n$.

Hope this helped